# GoRouter: Incorrect URL after pop

Tags: flutter, dart, web, flutter-go-router, gorouter

[image: 1]

What I noticed is that the query params in URL still there not remove when I pop back to previews screen.

Here is how the URLs look on web:

**Expected results:**
In the Address bar of the browser, it should: #/

**Actual results:**
In the Address bar of the browser, it shows: #/?sort=asc

using: go_route: ^6.0.0

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

final Map<String, dynamic> _families = {
  "f1": {
    "name": "Doe",
    "people": {
      "p1": {"name": "Jane", "age": 23},
      "p2": {"name": "John", "age": 6}
    }
  },
  "f2": {
    "name": "Wong",
    "people": {
      "p1": {"name": "June", "age": 51},
      "p2": {"name": "Xin", "age": 44}
    }
  }
};

void main() => runApp(App());

/// The main app.
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Creates an [App].
  App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  /// The title of the app.
  static const String title = 'GoRouter Example: Query Parameters';

  // add the login info into the tree as app state that can change over time
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp.router(
        routerConfig: _router,
        title: title,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      );

  late final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/',
    redirect: (context, state) {
      print('Subloc: ${state.subloc}');
    },
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    routerNeglect: true,
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const HomeScreen();
        },
        routes: <GoRoute>[
          GoRoute(
              name: 'family',
              path: 'family/:fid',
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                return FamilyScreen(
                  fid: state.params['fid']!,
                  asc: state.queryParams['sort'] == 'asc',
                );
              }),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}

/// The home screen that shows a list of families.
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Creates a [HomeScreen].
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(App.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          for (final String fid in _families.keys)
            ListTile(
              title: Text(_families[fid]['name']),
              onTap: () {
                context.goNamed(
                  'family',
                  params: {'fid': fid},
                  queryParams: {'sort': 'asc'},
                );
              },
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// The screen that shows a list of persons in a family.
class FamilyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Creates a [FamilyScreen].
  const FamilyScreen({required this.fid, required this.asc, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  /// The family to display.
  final String fid;

  /// Whether to sort the name in ascending order.
  final bool asc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Map<String, String> newQueries;
    final List<String> names = _families[fid]['people']
        .values
        .map<String>((dynamic p) => p['name'] as String)
        .toList();
    names.sort();
    if (asc) {
      newQueries = const <String, String>{'sort': 'desc'};
    } else {
      newQueries = const <String, String>{'sort': 'asc'};
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_families[fid]['name']),
        leading: BackButton(
          onPressed: () {
            GoRouter.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.goNamed('family',
                  params: <String, String>{'fid': fid},
                  queryParams: newQueries);
            },
            tooltip: 'sort ascending or descending',
            icon: const Icon(Icons.sort),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          for (final String name in asc ? names : names.reversed)
            ListTile(
              title: Text(name),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99122#issuecomment-1101725856) by one of the Go Router maintainers it is working as expected. Here is the comment with the unnecessary example code removed:

> This is WAI, this is the code I am using:
>
> [removed]
>
> The query parameter should persist since the entire route stack is built with the query parameter. If you want to clear the query param, you can go context.goto() without the query parameters

So the workaround is to call `context.go()` (it used to be `context.goto()`) to return to the previous previous page without the path parameters. Unfortunately that requires you to explicitly mention the page and I'm not sure how that is intended to work when the previous page also has its own query parameters which should be maintained.